# Ubuntu Cloud Maverick Network Question

Tags: ubuntu, eucalyptus

I'm installing Ubuntu Cloud Maverick at home

I have two systems, one with dual NICs, one with one nic.  The cluster controller is on my DSL network 192.168.1.x

I'm confused about what network to use for the cc

should it be 192.168.2.x or

something else like 10.10.x.x ?

Comment: Belongs in Serverfault

Answer (score 1):

Since this is you first UEC installation, I suggest following the instructions in the "Eucalyptus Beginner’s Guide – UEC edition v2.0 – Maverick".  it really help me setting up my first Eucalyptus cloud.

In the section "Installation & Configuration" they go over a full installation of a two machines cloud (which is exactly what you need).

http://cssoss.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/eucalyptus-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-%E2%80%93-uec%C2%A0edition/